# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in php codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, stdclass

I am trying to get data from my database , based on the company_name but getting error:

```
Error:Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

staff controller :

```
function index()
{
  $user_id =  $this->session->userdata('manager');
    // echo "index"; die; 
   $company_name = $this->staff_model->getCompanyName($user_id);

  //  print_r($company_name); 
  //      die;
   $data['staff'] = $this->staff_model->getStaffDetails($company_name);  //Error on this line

// print_r($data); 
// die;
   $this->load->view('manager/staff/index',$data);
}
```

staff_model

```
 <?php
class Staff_model extends CI_Model
{
        //table name: user_login
        function getCompanyName($user_id)
        {
          $company_name=$this->db->select('company_name')->from('user_login')->where(array('id' => $user_id,'delete_flag'=>0))->get()->row();
          return $company_name;
        }
        function getStaffDetails($company_name)
        { 
         $delete_flag=0;
         return  $this->db->get_where('user_login',array('delete_flag!='=>$delete_flag , 'company_name'=>$company_name))->result();  //Error on this line 

         // $query = $this->db->select('*')
          //   ->from('user_login')
          //   ->where("(delete_flag = '$delete_flag )")
          //   ->where("(company_name = $company_name)"); //Error on this line
         //   return $query();  }
```

And running

```
 print_r($company_name); 
            die;
```

results:

> stdClass Object ( [company_name] => ASGB )

Would appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: have you tried accessing the `company_name` property of `$company_name`? your `getCompanyName` method returns an object, not a string for a name

Comment: can you get `$data['staff'];`  ??

Comment: Which line is producing the error?

Comment: @lagbox yes I can access $company_name , as you can see ASGB is actually the company name

Comment: have you tried access the property of `$company_name` that is named `company_name`?   `$company_name->company_name`

Comment: @KUMAR no I can't , that is actually the line of Error as I indicated in the code as well

Comment: @ I have indicated in the code

Comment: @vickel I have tried , getting same error

Comment: @lahbox I added to my model , and yes it solved the problem , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in your Model of Codeigniter:-

**staff_model:-**

```
<?php
class Staff_model extends CI_Model
{
        //table name: user_login
        function getCompanyName($user_id)
        {
            $company_name = $this->db->select('company_name')
               ->from('user_login')
               ->where(array('id' => $user_id,'delete_flag'=>0))
               ->get()->row();
            return $company_name->company_name;   //change this.
        }
        
}
```

**Note:-**  This method returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. The result is returned as an `object`.

**$row = $query->row();**

**echo $row->column_name;** // accessing variable of row(); function by `->`(Arrow(->) operator:).

Fore more reference regarding this check :-

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows

Comment: yes currect, jut needed to add.  "$company_name->company_name;"   thank you very much  for the details.

Comment: @Roxana Slj please accept my answer if it solves your problem & future readers also.